# Use case of record and play in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I noticed that Notepad++ has this functionality of Record and Play. What could be the use case of this? Is this helpful in writing repetitive code?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, its a macro recorder.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do in n++, can be done again and again. It is like a preset. Very usefil for users who are doing the same task again and again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it as a macro recorder, yes.
Press "record", do something, press "stop" and then press "play" a few times.
It's really good when you have e.g. a lot of data and you want to format it for an import.